# How do I let my server receive background location while not in React Native App?

Tags: javascript, react-native, permissions, geolocation, hook

I have developed an app that allows me to track my users location when using they are in the app, but when I navigate outside of the app, my server loses its ability to track me, and I get disconnected. I have been told to use location.GetBackgroundPermissionAsync() but I cannot seem to write it right.

Below is the code I have written to track their current location. How would I rewrite it to track background location as well?

```
 async function getLocationAsync() {
        const { status, permissions } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION)
          if (status === 'granted'){
            return Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
          console.log('Your location is granted')
          } else {
            alert('Location Permission Not Given')
          }
      }

      getLocationAsync()
```